# is make_pair on the stack or heap?

Tags: c++, memory, dictionary

Do I need to allocate a pair if I insert it into a map from a different scope?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;
void parseInput(int argc, char *argv[], unordered_map<string, string>* inputs);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unordered_map<string, string>* inputs = new unordered_map<string, string>;
    parseInput(argc, argv, inputs);
    for(auto& it : *inputs){
        cout << "Key: " << it.first << " Value: " << it.second << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

void parseInput(int argc, char *argv[], unordered_map<string, string>* inputs)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<argc; i++){
        char *arg = argv[i];
        string param = string(arg);
        long pos = param.find_first_of("=");
        if(pos != string::npos){
            string key = param.substr(0, pos);
            string value = param.substr(pos+1, param.length()-pos);
            inputs->insert( make_pair(key, value) );//what happens when this goes out of scope
        }
    }
    for(auto& it : *inputs){
        cout << "Key: " << it.first << " Value: " << it.second << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating the `unordered_map` with `new`? Why not just `unordered_map<string, string> inputs;`?

Comment: You want to rethink dynamically creating the pointer inputs. An object is usally more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its fine:

```
inputs->insert( make_pair(key, value) );//what happens when this goes out of scope
```

std::make_pair returns the result by value.

The above has the same affect as:

```
inputs->insert( std::pair<std::string, std::string>(key, value) );
```

In both cases the value passed to insert() is copied(or moved) into the map.

Answer (score 8):

`make_pair(key, value)` returns a temporary object. The lifetime of that object ends at the end of the *full-expression* in which it is created (at the semicolon, basically).

The function `insert` creates a new object from that pair, which it puts into the map. The map stores this copy until the map is destroyed or the element is removed from the map.

Answer (score 5):

No, you're fine; the entire map entry value, consisting of key value and mapped value, is **copied** into the map data structure (or sometimes *moved*) when you insert it.

In C++11 you have a slightly more direct way of inserting an element via `m.emplace(key_value, mapped_value);`, which does not even create a temporary `pair`, or even better, `m.emplace(key_value, arg1, arg2, ...)`, which inserts an element with key `key_value` and mapped value `mapped_type(arg1, arg2, ...)`, without even creating a temporary for the mapped value.